# Posting information versus a question

Tags: support

I hope this is the right place to ask this question.  I'm just wondering what the correct procedure is when you wish to pass on some useful information, but you're not actually asking a question.  Do you post it as you would a question, and then answer it yourself?

Comment: [yes you do](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). just be sure to check to make sure the question hasn't already been asked before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could ask a question and answer it yourself, but if you just have some information, preferably a useful example, you want to share, you should consider posting it on [Documentation (beta)](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) instead.